# Inserting multiple data in jagged array from list

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I'm trying to insert xls formatted data into a jagged array so i can later
populate a dropdown with it. Problem is I can't seem to get around the
population of the array. I'm reaching for a list population of the data from the
"database" then adding it to the first row of the array, then reading the next
line. Here is what I created so far:

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
Excel.Range range;

string str;
int rCnt = 0;
int cCnt = 0;

xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("Location\\test.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
int x = range.Rows.Count;
int rows=0, columns=0;

string [] [] matrix = new string [x] [];
List<string> list= new List <string>();
for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
{
    for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
    {
        str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2;
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        list.Add(str);
    }
}
xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
xlApp.Quit();

releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
releaseObject(xlApp);
```

I just need a guideline about the best way to proceed. Either use the list and
then populate the array or perhaps another way.

Edit: For those with a similar problem i found a quick (might not be the most efficient though) solution which consists on getting a new for so it gets the values from the list to an array and then it adds to the matrix like so :

```
    for (int row =0; row<list.Count;row++)
    {
         string[] values = list.ToArray();
         matrix[rCnt-1] = values;
    }
    list.Clear();
```

But still. If you have any suggestions to help me out i would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Defius the solution you found seems like a good one. List is an array list, so the ToArray() is just an array copy. I doubt you will have any performance problems, most probably the element access from Excel will take longer.